# Android navigation component, backstack, nav graph, skip fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack, back-stack

I have following navigation in app.

A->B->**X**->**Y**->R

or

A->C->**X**->**Y**->R

or

A->**X**->**Y**->R

or

A->R

I don't want X and Y in backstack.

I know than in action Y->R I can do something like this:

```
        app:popUpTo="@id/B"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

or

```
        app:popUpTo="@id/C"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

But I don't want to pass param to X and Y and do separate action to go back to B or C. There must be a smarter way to do that.

Comment: When you move from Y to R, you want to remove X & Y and the back stack should be A->B->R OR A->C->R. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: In the two options you have shown in you question, i think `app:popUpToInclusive` should be `false` there, otherwise B/C will also be popped off. And to achieve what you want, you can set `app:popUpTo="@id/X"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`

Comment: I forgot a few paths. I edited a question. So in that case in which navigation action should I put this popUpTo?

Comment: In your action Y->R, add the code that I wrote in last comment.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. When you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238869/discussion-between-kkkkk-and-arpit-shukla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action from  Y->R, you can add:

```xml
app:popUpTo="@id/X"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

This will pop everything till X (including X) and you will get your desired backstack.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I didn't realize that the `popUpTo` defined the part of the stack that was removed.  I thought it referred to the destination you wanted to go to.